# SingalR in console app

Tags: c#, web-applications, signalr

Hi I am trying  to run a signalR insude a console app.
this is my code so far

```
    class Program
{
    static IDisposable dis = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            dis = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:10476");
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        if (dis != null)
            dis.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

public class myHub : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
        Clients.All.OK();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

this is my client code

```
function send() {
var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:10476");
var hub = connection.createHubProxy("myHub");
hub.on("OK", function () {
    alert("HI");
});
connection.start({jsonp: true})
    .done(function () {
        console.log('connected');
        hub.invoke("Hello");
    })
    .fail(function (a) {
        console.log('not connected' + a);
    });
```

}

note: my client and the hub are separate (I want the client to be a browser extension while the server is an app on my computer) 
however when I call this function the browser sat "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access."
is my client code correct?

Comment: Are you running that as administrator? Probably the app cannot open the port 476 without administrator rights. Or it could be used by another application. You should always use ports above 10000 to be safe

Comment: Please don't do that. Changing the question after it was solved is considered very bad behavior on Stack Overflow. You should rollback those edits and ask a new question

Comment: It wasn't fully solved,it was just a part of the question .
but I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Your SignalR server and web server that responsible for loading your page should be the same if you didn't enable CORS. If you want them to be in separated web applications, You have to enable cors in your SignalR application. For doing this in the Startup.cs:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
 {
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
      map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
      map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
  }
```

For more information please see link below: 
https://cmatskas.com/signalr-cross-domain-with-cors/